# Tracing IP addresses in PeopleSoft

Tags: peoplesoft

We have a generic username in PeopleSoft and I was wondering if it was possible to track who was using it through the IP address. Basically I would like to know the IP address of the person who used the generic username to make a few changes in the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PeopleSoft records this information in the PSACCESSLOG table with the fields OPRID and LOGIPADDRESS.

If your users are in the same network as the PeopelSoft system, you'll see the IP-username combination and you'll have what you want.

If your users are behind a Reverse Proxy Server, the IP of the RPS is logged. You could examine the signon peoplecode to see if you can change this.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks - but it did lead me to a follow up question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45199756/ps-table-that-stores-information-about-user-roles, maybe you could help?)